# Linux RHEL, как повесить на прерывание CTRL + SHIFT +  ?

Tags: terminal, putty, rhel, linux

Всем доброго дня!
Отцы, подскажите как мне повесить на сигнал прерывания какую либо сложную комбинацию (**CTRL + SHIFT + SOMEKEY**)? Например что бы задать для прерывания комбинацию **CTRL + C** я пишу **stty intr ^C**. А что писать для комбинации, например, из трёх клавиш я понять/найти не могу.

Comment: Может быть, это будет полезным: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113589/how-to-have-longer-key-bindings-for-stty

Comment: ну так можно и просто свою обертку сделать вокруг приложения используя ncurses или как-нить еще. тс я бы посоветовал лучше перехватывать SIGTERM и спрашивать подтверждения (например - для выхода надо нажать не просто ^C, а ^C,^E)

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, ^C в данном контексте это символ (&003) с терминала , а не комбинация клавиш.

т.е. ответ - никак.

частично можно для вот таких:

```
$ ascii '^@'
ASCII 0/0 is decimal 000, hex 00, octal 000, bits 00000000: called ^@, NUL
Official name: Null
C escape: '\0'
Other names:

$ ascii '^^'
ASCII 1/14 is decimal 030, hex 1e, octal 036, bits 00011110: called ^^, RS
Official name: Record Separator
```

но я бы так делать не стал

вот подтверждение из `stty --help`:

> **intr СИМВОЛ**     СИМВОЛ будет посылать сигнал прерывания